# Этимология слова "ошеломить"

Tags: этимология

Есть ли связь между глаголом ошеломить и существительным шлем?

Answer (score 5):

> **Есть ли** связь между глаголом ошеломить и существительным шлем?

**[Есть.](http://etymological.academic.ru/3432)**

> **ошеломить**
>
> Искон. Суф.-преф. производное от *шелом* «шлем». См. *шлем*. *Ошеломить*
>   буквально — «сбить с врага шлем».
>
> *Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.*

Comment: Словарь 1847 : "Ошеломлять... 1)Приводить въ безпамятство **ударомъ по шелому** или  по головѣ 2)..."

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что враг здесь ни при чем, мы же и друзей можем ошеломить какой-нибудь удивительной новостью.

Скорее всего, ошеломить (сбить шлем) в нашей реальности - это все равно что вытащить наушники у собеседника, то есть убрать то, что мешает слышать.

Comment: **Vera**, прочитайте повнимательнее, **о чём** спрашивала Оксана: **Этимология** слова “ошеломить”.

Comment: Беру этимологический словарь. Ошеломить - 14-16 век, от русского "шелом" (шлем), поразить, удивить, дословно - "сбить шлем".  А потом еще надо ударить по открытой голове, чтоб удивился? Вот если бы ошеломить - это ударить по голове, тогда будет чувствительное воздействие, но у нас - это всего лишь сбить шлем.

Comment: _Vera: Беру этимологический словарь..._ === И это правильно! А предыдущее Ваше "Скорее всего, ошеломить (сбить шлем) **в нашей реальности**..." -- это уже не этимологический, а **толковый** словарь, к поставленному Оксаной вопросу вряд ли имеющий отношение. ИМХО

Comment: Объясните этимологию: почему это у Шанского ошеломить - это сбить шлем именно с ВРАГА, а не просто сбить шлем.

Comment: _Почему?_ Наверное, потому, что с друзьями в старину по-иному обращались.

Comment: Я понимаю, что сильно удивить - это все равно что ударить по голове.  Непонятно только, зачем в этом случае сбивать шлем. Можно просто ударить по шлему, эффект будет не хуже. Значит, дело не в ударе, а в чем?

Comment: В самом начале жизни всем детям в школах и умных передачах объясняют этимологию слова ОШЕЛОМИТЬ. Как дети малые, ей-богу.

Comment: Это не ответ, а бездоказательная фантазия на заданную тему. Вы видите связь между "ошеломить" и "убрать то, что мешает слышать"?

Comment: Вопрос от "малых детей": 1) Какова словообразовательная схема глагола "ошеломить". 2)  Это приставочный  или приставочно-суффиксальный способ образования? 3) Каково значение приставки О? Если формантом считать О+И, то его обычное значение  - это покрыть чем-то со всех сторон (окаймить, оцепить, озадачить), но не сбить/удалить (но может быть, есть и такое значение, только это доказать надо). Если "шелом - шеломить", то здесь какое значение? Приведите похожие примеры, обозначьте семантику.

Answer (score 2):

Да, слова этимологически связаны, но исходную фразу [словарь Макса Фасмера](http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Oshelomit-9373.html) толкует по-другому:

> **Ошеломить** ошеломи́ть производное от шело́м "**шлем, головка топора, обух**", т. е. первонач. "**ударить обухом по голове**"; см. Преобр. I, 674; Торбьёрнссон I, 100. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Т.е. не "сбить шлем/шелом", а ударить этим "шеломом" по голове, где одним из значений слова "шелом", помимо собственно шлема, есть еще и обух топора.

По той же ссылке есть толкование из словаря Ушакова:

> ошеломлю, ошеломишь, сов. (к ошеломлять), кого-что. Крайне поразить, изумить, озадачить. Фантасмагория, да и только! - почти ошеломленный от изумления проговорил генерал. Достоевский. Он ошеломил меня своим вопросом. (Первонач. **ударить в бою по шелому, т.е. шлему.**)

Comment: Интересно, а почему эта столь очевидная версия подвергается какой-то ревизии? Да еще с фантазиями?

Comment: И еще. Не называйте, пожалуйста, Макса Юлиуса Фридриха Фасмера "Максимом")))

Comment: @behemothus Черт, точно! Насчет "ревизии с фантазиями" не понял.

Comment: Ревизии и фантазии - это другие ответы. Вы же пишете "по-другому", значит читали.

Comment: А Фасмер - да. Или Макс - или уж, если на русский манер, Максимилиан Романович.

Comment: Думаю что это не "ревизии с фантазиями" а параллельная реальность. Кто-то у Фасмера посмотрит, а кто-то в устаревшем словаре (не говоря уже о собственных фантазиях). Уже сколько раз сталкивался с тем, что толкования из научно-популярной литературы уже 50 лет как считаются устаревшими, а все кочуют по школьным словарям и т.п. Вот и это "ошеломить" - как в "Веселых картинках" или "Мурзилке" написали "ударить по шлему", так и засело в голове на всю жизнь. Вот Н. М. Шанский и Т. А. Боброва не сами же "сбить шлем" придумали - тоже скорее всего в серьезном словаре нашли.

Answer (score 1):

хм... может, все-таки не снять, а "надеть шлем", приставка о- ни при каком раскладе не означает раздевания.... а может, и не шлем в корне, а шоломок (шапка), шеломайка (голова), или еще какое-нибудь народное, не зафиксированное в словарях "шелометь"...

Answer (score 0):

**Ошеломить** - не сбить **шелом**, а ударить **о шелом**(это к ответу Алены). А обух топора, как **шелом**, вероятнее всего и происходит от **ошеломить**, а не наоборот.